# Why is JConsole not backward compatible when connecting via a proxy?

Tags: java, jconsole

I have a remote application running on JDK 1.7. When I attempt to attach to it using  from JDK 1.6 or JDK 1.8 via a proxy

```
jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=${proxy_port} service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:${jmx_port}/jmxrmi
```

I get the same message:

```
Connection Failed: Retry?
The connection to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:xxxx/jmxrmi did not succeed.
Would you like to try again?
```

I expect 1.6 not to be viable for more recent versions, but thought that 1.8 would be able to take care of previous versions.

When I just use `jconsole` (instead of the proxy script) locally I *can* use both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.8 to connect to JVMs running on JDK 1.7.

Comment: Is it really not backward compatible? I've had issues in the past associated with JConsole and the application to connect to running under different users in windows environments. In 1.7 it simply wont see the process, maybe its something similar here.

Comment: @MarkW I've added more detail -- this is only happening for me over a proxy.  That makes sense since I was pretty sure I'd not cared about JDK versions when using JConsole until just recently.